# Reshaping txt file to match the desired format with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Good day to everyone. I have a bad txt file, where there are 11 items in odd rows and 3 items in even rows, but I need 14 columns. When I use `np.loadtxt('Boston.txt')`, it gives

> ValueError: Wrong number of columns at line 2

when I use `pd.read_csv(('Boston.txt'), sep='\s+')`, it works somehow, but shows something like this (11 items as columns, 3 items in first row with 8 NaNs):

> 0.00632   18.00   2.310   0   0.5380  6.5750  65.20   4.0900  1   296.0   15.30
>
> 0 396.90000   4.98    24.00   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

Can someone help me to solve this problem to have 14 columns with naming: column=['CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD', 'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV']. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get an answer, so did with common python, maybe it could help someone.

```
columns = ('CRIM', 'ZN', 'INDUS', 'CHAS', 'NOX', 'RM', 'AGE', 'DIS', 'RAD',
           'TAX', 'PTRATIO', 'B', 'LSTAT', 'MEDV')
boston_dict = {}
for item in columns:
    boston_dict[item] = []

with open('Boston.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        total_list = (line + f.readline()).strip().split()
        for key, value in zip(boston_dict.keys(), total_list):
            boston_dict[key].append(float(value))
        line = f.readline()
```